# How expensive is HTML UL LI element (list element)?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, filenames, pre

I want to add a list of filenames for each [OpenBSD port/package](http://ports.openbsd.su/) in my ports-readmes fork, similar to how [ports-readme-dancer](http://ports.su/databases/ports-readmes-dancer) does it.

However, I've noticed that ports-readme-dancer pages are somewhat slow to scroll in my Mozilla SeaMonkey.  The source indicates that each filename is part of an unordered list, with a `list-style: none;` and `font-family: courier;`.

Would I be better off using `li` for each filename as above, or gather them all in a single `pre`?

**How slow is each individual `li` compared to a line of text within `pre`?**  For example, [www/apache-httpd-openbsd](http://ports.su/www/apache-httpd-openbsd) would have to list about **500** filenames, and seems slowish to scroll in Mozilla SeaMonkey with each of them being a separate `li`.

Comment: Slow to scroll, you mean after everything has been loaded? I can hardly imagine that using a list slows things down. Maybe you should be on the lookout for onscroll event handlers or something.

Comment: @MrLister, yes, after everything's loaded.  My only other guess is another list, right above this list, being a column-based table; but the list of 500 elements itself was not columnised.

Answer (score 1):

For list use list element `li`.

Question is invalid. `li` element itself can't be slow, context of performance is missing. So `li` is as fast and as slow as `pre`.

Each tag is DOM node which requires rendering. Selecting DOM node with CSS selector is very fast for large mounts of DOM nodes. Javascript selectors will get a bigger hit depending on DOM node quantity.

For scrolling you wouldn't get any noticeable performance difference.

Comment: I agree. Comparing `li` with `pre` for 500 entries is, at best, a micro-optimization, that gets into your way looking for the real culprit for slow scrolling. Try it with a plain HTML file (no CSS, no JS), and I'm quite sure, you will find no difference in scroll behavior.